# Chrome extension: chrome.windows.update(windowId, {focused:true}) doesn't work on windows 10

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that creates multiple windows then focuses on one of them using..

```
 chrome.windows.update(windowId, {focused:true})
```

This works on my mac but on windows 10 only pulls the window to the front on windows, it won't accept any input from the keyboard until clicking on the window.

How can I force it to accept input as well?

I found a post from 2012 about chrome having issues with focus but nothing since?

UPDATE: tested on chromebook and windows 8.1 with same issue

Comment: Looks like a bug. Report it on https://bugs.chromium.org

Comment: so a workaround then? Because I saw they same bug posted 4 years ago with no change made to chrome

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=10506

definitely a known issue

Comment: I would try something crazy, like maybe minimizing the window, then restoring it.